# How can i extract the windows phone backup from skydrive and check on my computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7, onedrive

I have windows phone and I have enabled backups on skydrive. I can see the Backup under device backups on skydrive. But how can i download it to my computer and can view the files in this ?

I am an asp.net developer. So any technical solution will also be acceptable.